# How to set a font size as variable in ZPL

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

Hi I need to set a variable as the font scale in the ZPL code:

How Can I set this ScaleFont1 to be used in several parts of the label?

```
#ScaleFont2=64,42,20:58,34,30:56,28,60#
^XA^FWN^XZ
^XA^SZ2^JMA^MCY^PMN^PW822~JSN^JZY^POI^LH15,5^LRN^XZ
^XA^PR8^XZ
^XA^MMT
^FT15,305^A0N,<ScaleFont1>^FD<ReceiverAddressLine1>^FS
^FT15,345^A0N,<ScaleFont1>^FD<ReceiverAddressLine2>^FS
^FT15,385^A0N,<ScaleFont1>^FD<Address1>^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ^CF command sets the default Font Sizes to be used for throughout the Label. that should allow you to set it once, I changed the Sample 
[Here](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=1&height=2&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5ECF0%2C10%2C9%0A%5EXA%5EFWN%5EXZ%0A%5EXA%5ESZ2%5EJMA%5EMCY%5EPMN%5EPW822~JSN%5EJZY%5EPOI%5ELH15%2C5%5ELRN%5EXZ%0A%5EXA%5EPR8%5EXZ%0A%5EXA%5EMMT%0A%5EFO15%2C305%5EFD%3CReceiverAddressLine1%3E%5EFS%0A%5EFO15%2C345%5EFD%3CReceiverAddressLine2%3E%5EFS%0A%5EFO15%2C385%5EFD%3CAddress1xx%3E%5EFS%0A%5EPQ1%2C0%2C1%2CY%0A%5EXZ)